# Store an IF Statement into Variable for LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, variables, storage, local

I am making a speeding app, right now I created an IF statement that when the user goes over 20km/ph an alert is popped informing them, I want the user to set the value of this so it is not predefined into 20 from an input field in the HTML which then stores it into local storage and changes the value of the variable,

the trouble is, it's an IF statement and I do not know how to rewrite it so it fits a variable format.

```
     if (speed > 20) {
         alert("speeding");
                    }
```

Comment: wrap a function around your statement which you can then use as variable `var speedTest = function(speed) {if(speed > 20) alert("speeding");};` then you can call it whereever you want like speedTest(50)

Comment: 'function speeding {
if (speed > 20) {
         alert("speeding");
                    }}'
Can I use speeding as a variable

Answer (score 0):

```js
const speed = 10;

function checkSpeed(limit) {
  if (speed > limit) {
    alert("speeding");
  }
}

checkSpeed(5);
```

Comment: Sorry if this may sound stupid but I am a novice at this,
You mind telling me what const speed = 10 means? 
and 
checkSpeed(5)?
Thank you

Comment: @Syystole I think that you should seriously start with some basic tutorials. `const speed=10` is simply declaring a variable. `checkSpeed(5)` is calling the function

Comment: yes, thank you. I am trying, slowly.

One more question if you don't mind

Since I am using Local Storage, once I receive the value from the input in the HTML I would need to set it here do i do this with this code
localStorage.setItem('checkspeed',checkspeed.value);?

Comment: @Syystole Yes. Don't try to do something complicated. You should really stat with the basics

Answer (score 0):

This does what you've described. There's an HTML field which can be populated with a speed, then whenever you change that and hit enter the `JavaScript` picks it up, reads in the limit and checks to see if the speed is greater than that.

You'll need to put something in to check that the limit is an integer (or you'll get an error in `parseInt`). I wasn't sure how you were going to set the speed, so I just left it as a variable.

```js
document.getElementById('limit').addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    
    checkSpeed(parseInt(this.value));

}, false);

function checkSpeed(limit){
    
    speed = 30;
    
    if (speed > limit) {
      alert("speeding");
    }
    
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="limit">
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this,
I don't mean to sound ungrateful but I am trying to do it without the use of external framework and plugins (Jquery), instead I'm trying to use local storage to store the data

Comment: That's been edited to not use `jQuery`, should just work with plain JavaScript now :).